# Creating and running .sh file from R studio using system command

Tags: r, bash

I am trying to write a sh file from R studio and then execute the .sh file from the R studio itself. I am using:

```
writeLines(c("#!/bin/bash","activate samtools","metaphlan2.py ERR479000_1.fastq.gz,ERR479000_2.fastq.gz --bowtie2out ./temp/ERR479000.bowtie2.bz2 --input_type fastq > ./temp/MetaPhlAn2.txt"), "MetaPhlAn2.sh")
system('chmod u+r+x MetaPhlAn2.sh')
```

The sh file is running properly when I use the terminal, but when I try to run the file from the R studio using:

```
system('./MetaPhlAn2.sh')
```

I get the following:

```
./MetaPhlAn2.sh: line 2: activate: command not found
./MetaPhlAn2.sh: line 3: metaphlan2.py: command not found
Warning message:
In system("./MetaPhlAn2.sh") : error in running command
```

Why the sh file is not running from Rstudio but run properly from the terminal? Thanks for your help!

Comment: My guess would be that the bash that you open isn't sourcing your `~/.bashrc` file ("vanilla run") and doesn't have access to the (virtual environment) tools you're using.

Comment: What OS are you using? Where is `activate` defined? Can you run `which activate` in your terminal? Does it return the same as when you run `Sys.which("activate")` in the R console?

Comment: thank you, I am using a mac, activate is for a conda package that has the script, which activate gives "/opt/anaconda2/bin/activate" and Sys.which("activate") in R returns activate 
      ""

Comment: So it sounds like your `PATH` at the terminal (`echo $PATH` at system terminal) must be different than the PATH seen by R `(Sys.getenv("PATH") at R console)`. So is `samtools` the name of an anaconda environment. Is the `metaphlan2.py` script in the exact same filter as the `MetaPhlAn2.sh` file? What is your default shell in your terminal? This seems to be more related to anaconda2 that R in this case.

Comment: yes, samtools is a anaconda environment. metaphlan2.py is part of samtools, while I have written MetaPhlAn2.sh script to run on my local files. I am not sure how to find default shell in terminal

Comment: I temporarily solve this by adding my terminal path in R using Sys.setenv(PATH="//opt/anaconda2/envs/samtools/bin:/opt/anaconda2/bin:/opt/anaconda2/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/m197897/Desktop/Applications:/Users/m197897/Desktop/Applications/metabat:/opt/X11/bin"). But looks like I need to do it for every R session